# How to make a function instead of overusing if statements in python?

Tags: python

Working with a morse code translator! 
I have a program that gets an input from a user, to example "Hello", and then I need to read of each character and transform it to morse code time units.

The way I do it is that I use short period for 0 and long period for 1. I made a lot of variables from A-Z, 0-9, and wrote "byte" code for each. It got pretty big.

Then eventually I had to make a function that reads the input and puts all the zeros and ones in one big string with help of these variables I made. And here I got stuck, because I wasn't ready to make 35 if statements.

```py
'''
Function that compiles all the letters from input together
to a 0/1 code
'''
morse = "" # the string that will include "byte code"

def compile(text):
    for c in text:
        # here I got stuck


# Alphabet
A = "01"
B = "1000"
C = "1010"
D = "100"
E = "0"
# .....
```

I would like to know if there is any actual solution to this mess, how to write this function without overusing if statements.

I tried to be clear as possible, hope you understand.

Comment: Is the alphabet hard coded somewhere?

Comment: Try putting the alphabet and digits in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary to map from letters to codes.

```
morse_dict = {"A": "01", "B": "1000", "C": "1010", ...}

def compile(text):
    return " ".join(morse_dict[c] for c in text.upper())
```

Comment: Thanks worked smoothly, but I had to use c.upper() instead of upper(c) to make it work. Now I have to put it all in a dict ;(

Comment: Seems like using `morse_dict[c] for c in text.upper()` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will be to use a dictionary. Compile it like so:

```
alphabet = {
    "A": "01"
    "B": "02"
    ...
    "Z": "01111010"
}
```

And then in your for loop, you can do:

```
def compile(text):
    morse_string = ""
    for c in text.upper():
        morse_string += alphabet[c]
    return morse_string
```

Or something along those lines.

You can find more about dictionaries (and other datastructures) [here.](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Your dictionary values are numbers, not strings, you can't concatenate them without calling `str()`. Also, they don't look like Morse code sequences.

Comment: Good catches, fixed. I feel your generator based response is probably a better solution anyways.